# Missing pattern plot - No. of Missing values in each column in R

Tags: r

I want to plot the pattern of missing data using “VIM” package. I have used the following code for the plot,

```
aggr(tr1, col=c('blue','tomato'), numbers=TRUE, sortVars=FALSE, sortCombs=TRUE, combined=TRUE, only.miss= TRUE, labels=names(tr1), cex.axis=.6, prop = FALSE, ylab = "Pattern of missing data")
```

[image: Missing pattern plot]

But I am not getting no. of missing values for each column. Please help me on this issue.

**Reproducible Code**

```
library(VIM)
tr <- sleep
aggr(tr, col=c('blue','tomato'), numbers=TRUE, sortVars=FALSE, sortCombs=TRUE, combined=TRUE, only.miss= TRUE, labels=names(tr), cex.axis=.6, prop = FALSE, ylab = "Pattern of missing data")
```

Thanks,
Balaji

Comment: @akrun please find the updated question with reproducible code.

Comment: You may need to remove `combined` parameter as it produces a small version of the barplot. `aggr(tr, col=c('blue','tomato'), numbers=TRUE, sortVars=FALSE, sortCombs=TRUE, only.miss= TRUE, labels=names(tr), cex.axis=.6, prop = FALSE)`

Comment: Hi prem, i dont want 2 charts because of space constraint. I want no. of missing values in each column to reflect in the combined chart itself.

Comment: @BalajiN, did you find a solution for your question? Are there any good packages for ggplot to plot missing data?